# render to cubemap tutorial in WebGL

Tags: webgl

in my program I have a lightsource in the middle of the scene with objects around it.

I would like to do shadowmapping for it. I already know how to do shadowmapping for a lightsource that is somewhere outside the screen.  So my idea was to render to a cubemap around my lightbulb, each side of the cubemap a shadowmap, like I am used to.

How do I render to a cubemap? Is there a tutorial? Is this the way to go?

Comment: [example](http://webglsamples.org/dynamic-cubemap/dynamic-cubemap.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In webgl you render to a cubemap by rendering to each face of the cubemap, so 6 draws per cubemap.

You attach one side of a cube map to the FBO by calling 
`gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X+side, glTextureCube, 0);`

You also need a different view matrix for each side. This is usually done with the .lookAt function. The relevant look direction and up vector are as follows:

```
var ENV_CUBE_LOOK_DIR = [
    new Vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    new Vec3(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    new Vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
    new Vec3(0.0, -1.0, 0.0),
    new Vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
    new Vec3(0.0, 0.0, -1.0)
];

var ENV_CUBE_LOOK_UP = [
    new Vec3(0.0, -1.0, 0.0),
    new Vec3(0.0, -1.0, 0.0),
    new Vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
    new Vec3(0.0, 0.0, -1.0),
    new Vec3(0.0, -1.0, 0.0),
    new Vec3(0.0, -1.0, 0.0)
];
```

The projection matrix is `var CUBE_PROJECTION = mat4.perspective(Math.PI/2, aspect, near, far);`

Then at rendering time, you do:

```
//change to right framebuffer...
for (var side = 0; side<6;side++){
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X+side, glTextureCube, 0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    view = mat4.lookAt(camera.pos, camera.pos + ENV_CUBE_LOOK_DIR[side], ENV_CUBE_LOOK_UP[side]);
    viewProjection = CUBE_PROJECTION * view;
    // upload uniforms
    // render
}
```

Comment: do I set the viewport when rendering into the framebuffer? 
for rendering onto a 2D texture I used a empty 2D texture with the same size as I set the viewport to:


 gl.viewport(0, 0, OFFSCREEN_HEIGHT,OFFSCREEN_WIDTH);


        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, OFFSCREEN_HEIGHT, OFFSCREEN_WIDTH, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

Comment: Yes, you have to change viewport to the size of the cube map texture when rendering to the cube map.

Comment: I currently get the Error: WebGL: A texture is going to be rendered as if it were black, as per the OpenGL ES 2.0.24 spec section 3.8.2, because it is a cube map texture, with a minification filter not requiring a mipmap, and is not cube complete (as defined in section 3.7.10).
What am I missing? :(

Comment: Not sure, probably one of your texture parameter is off. Maybe to go read the specs to find out? :)